# CodeIgniter: set_message for max_length[x]

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling, validation

How do you set an error message for `max_length` and `min_length` rules. For instance, if I set a rule `max_length[6]`, I'd like the error message to display
`Max characters allowed: 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gAMBOOKa,

create a 'new' rule that also checks for max_length

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|_max_length[12]');
```

and for the method..

```
function _max_length($val)
    {
        if (strlen($this->input->post('username')) > $val)
        {
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('_max_length', 'Max characters allowed: 5')
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
```

add this to your controller as a new rule and set the message like so ---^

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and even though this post is old, there's no correct answer.. You just have to use the string placeholder %s in second place of your message. In the documentation (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors) there is an example for a field not being empty:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
```

There, it uses the %s placeholder for the name of the field, but if you modify the 'max_length' message putting the field name first and the length second like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'The field %s max length is %s');
```

it will work. Is not the best solution, but that one works for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

**application/language/en/en_lang.php I have this:**

```
$lang['name'] = "Name";
$lang['form_required'] = "is required.";
```

**application/language/es/es_lang.php I have this:**

```
$lang['name'] = "Nombre";
$lang['form_required'] = "es requiero.";
```

**application/controllers/yourController.php I have this:**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', $this->lang->line('name'), 'required|alpha|xss_clean');

$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s ' . $this->lang->line('form_required'));
```

I hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel is correct. Per [CodeIgniter's documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user%5Fguide/libraries/form%5Fvalidation.html#settingerrors), you can override the default error message for any validation rule (such as "min_length", "max_length", etc.) like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('validation_rule', 'Your message here');
```

So, in your example you could do:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'Max characters allowed: 5');
```

Simply include that where your validation rules exist.

Comment: I know to override the default message but how do I incorporate the length parameter in the new message? 5 in this case. I have multiple fields with varying lengths, I would prefer not to write a message for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has one of the better documentations out of all the frameworks. Read the userguide on their site or the one in your CI directory.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in `system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php` and you'll find

```
$lang['max_length'] = "The %s field can not exceed %s characters in length.";
```

Which is easily overridden by copying it to

```
application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php
```

And changing it to the string you'd like. Do **not** edit the file in `system/` directly, then it'll be overwritten if you upgrade CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add a new method. You may set a custom message to a form validation error by accessing the "max_length" rule as shown below.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]', array('required' => 'Username is required.','max_length' => 'Max characters allowed: 5')
);
```

*Note: This is also applicable for "min_length" rule.*